# Getting the server number when using --auto-servernum with xvfb-run

Tags: xorg, xvfb

When I execute an application with `xvfb-run`, I can either explicitly specify an X11 server number (i.e. `44`), or I can use `--auto-servernum`, which will assign one for me.

If I use `--auto-servernum`, how do I know what number it picked?

I'm trying to use this in a script, so if `xvfb-run` could output that somewhere so that I can use subsequent commands on the right X11 server, that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is put into the `DISPLAY` environment variable.  You can see this by running

```
printenv DISPLAY
xvfb-run printenv DISPLAY
printenv DISPLAY
```

The first and last will show your regular display, the middle one will show the `xvfb` one.